# Configure SSL on a Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application object?

Tags: c#, iis-7, ssl

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to programatically enable the "Require SSL" check box and change the "Client Certificates" option to "Require" in IIS Application using **Microsoft.Web.Administration**.

All of the questions on the net I've found relate to configuring it on the web site itself, but I need only need to turn it on for a few Applications hosted on the site.

Anyone have experience doing this?

I tried this to start:

```
application.EnabledProtocols = "http,https";
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

But I got an error:

> Filename:
>   \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config Error:
>   Cannot write configuration file

Which is odd, because from what I've read, I gather that file maintains IIS configuration, but it doesn't exist in Windows (I can't open it in TextPad), but it does exist in the command prompt and I can `more` it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did more searching, found [this](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication), ended up writing this:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", siteName + "/" + vdRelativePath);
accessSection["sslFlags"] = "Ssl,SslRequireCert";
```

Where siteName and vdRelativePath are "Default Web Site" and "/Application/Path".

You can use `config.GetLocationPaths()` to find the right path if "Default Web Site/Application/Path" doesn't work for you.