# Access  IIS  Websites Properties  Using ServerManager

Tags: c#, iis, appcmd, servermanager

I am able to display the sites in my IIS using the `serverManager.Site`. Is there any way to list the files in each of the Website. I need to change RequireSSL property of one of the File. Is that Possible using ServerManager? Or any other way to do the same like appcmd ? Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561588/configure-ssl-on-a-microsoft-web-administration-application-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Solution in the link provided by Antonio in the comment. Basically we can change the  ApplicationHost Config File to get it done. Heres the link again

[Configure SSL on a Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561588/configure-ssl-on-a-microsoft-web-administration-application-object)